# Facebook token with offline access that doesn't expire

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, access-token, facebook-access-token

Hi I am trying to generate a Facebook access token that has offline access and doesn't expire.

We are currently generating the token using

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?type=user_agent&client_id=OurAppId&redirect_uri=http://OurSite.com&scope=read_stream,offline_access

which generates the following

http://OurSite.com/#access_token=BWLjKqmm5I4dBAJUoJsbrZBMjqUTYd5oUVKdMDf0nyZBkBMnl62F5lFPqliU4cfAaI9vHjwhfgpsidjw5zrBfg4M5RftQcYHkD2rf3rCmsfd4vyxW1SPkg1bfUS3NuY2MwwhUGD159LztlpgkjSunVwf8LZA70NoefhRt1fhYPZCpSJ35gjgs6SxHwZDZD&expires_in=5500

But this expires pretty quickly. The fields in the Graph Explorer are not very obvious either.

[image]

How can we generate a token with offline access that doesn't expire

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook has [deprecated and removed the offline_access permission](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). This permission previously allowed you to get a long-lived token. It is no longer possible to do so.